# Issue with converting XML file into Excel. Can someone help me in this regard?

Tags: java, excel

I have found a code in online to convert XML file to Excel but when i opened the spreadsheet, the rows are not in proper order i mean 3rd record in XML is written on 1st row, 2nd on 2nd and 1st in 3rd row, Can anyone help me where i did a mistake?

XML:

```
<book>
<person>
  <first>hi</first>
  <last>hi2</last>
  <age>56</age>
</person>
<person>
  <first>hello</first>
  <last>hello2</last>
  <age>25</age>
</person>
<person>
  <first>madhu</first>
  <last>madhu2</last>
  <age>23</age>
</person>
</book>
```

JAVA CODE:

```
package ToSpreadSheet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class Example {
public static void main(String argv[]) {

    ArrayList<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> lastNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ages = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File("C:/Users/emademp/Desktop/persons.xml"));

        // normalize text representation
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element of the doc is :\" "+ doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName() + "\"");
        NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");
        int totalPersons = listOfPersons.getLength();
        System.out.println("Total no of people : " + totalPersons);
        for (int s = 0; s < listOfPersons.getLength(); s++) 
        {
            Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(s);
            if (firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
            {
                Element firstPersonElement = (Element) firstPersonNode;
                NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("first");
                Element firstNameElement = (Element) firstNameList.item(0);
                NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("First Name : "+ ((Node) textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                firstNames.add(((Node) textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                NodeList lastNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("last");
                Element lastNameElement = (Element) lastNameList.item(0);
                NodeList textLNList = lastNameElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("Last Name : "+ ((Node) textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                lastNames.add(((Node) textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                NodeList ageList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("age");
                Element ageElement = (Element) ageList.item(0);
                NodeList textAgeList = ageElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("Age : "+ ((Node) textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                ages.add(((Node) textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
            }// end of if clause

        }// end of for loop with s var
        for(String firstName:firstNames)
        {
            System.out.println("firstName : "+firstName);
        }
        for(String lastName:lastNames)
        {
            System.out.println("lastName : "+lastName);
        }
        for(String age:ages)
        {
            System.out.println("age : "+age);
        }

    } 
    catch (SAXParseException err) 
    {
        System.out.println("** Parsing error" + ", line "+ err.getLineNumber() + ", uri " + err.getSystemId());
        System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage());
    } 
    catch (SAXException e) 
    {
        Exception x = e.getException();
        ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (Throwable t) 
    {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }


    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("XML sheet");

    Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
  for(int i=0;i<firstNames.size();i++)
  {
     data.put(i+"",new Object[]{firstNames.get(i),lastNames.get(i),ages.get(i)});
    }
    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();




    int rownum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset) {
         Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : objArr) {
             Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if (obj instanceof Date)
                cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Boolean)
                cell.setCellValue((Boolean) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof String)
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Double)
                cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
        }
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/emademp/Desktop/book1.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}// end of main

}
```

Spreadsheet output:

```
madhu madhu2 23
hello hello2 25
hi hi2 56
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a lot of unnecessary extra work. Your problem comes from the fact that you put your data into `HashMap` and then use a key set to iterate over the items. The contract of `HashMap` states that it does not maintain order, and the keys in a key set will be in an unspecified random sequence.  It just happens that in your case they come out in reverse order.

As to fixing the problem there is no need to use a `HashMap` at all.  When you are initially extracting the data from XML, store the name and age in a new custom class and create a list of those objects, then iterate over that list to create rows in the spreadsheet. I.e., instead of the lists `firstNames`, `lastNames` and `ages`:

```
class Person
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String age;
    // constructor, getters and setters
}
...
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then create one new `Person` for each input block, store in the `people` list, then write to spreadsheet by iterating over `people`.